# Resizing two adjacent (snapped) windows using keyboard only (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, accessibility

If I have one window snapped on the left of my screen, and another snapped on the right of my screen, I can resize the width of both simultaneously by clicking and dragging the divider between them. Is it possible to move this divider using the keyboard only?